# Creating a small pdf from JPGs to be web optimized

Tags: python

I have a number of images in a folder (around 2000 images) with approximately 150KB each. They have a dpi of 96. I want to create a pdf with these images as small as possible. I am using PyPDF2 to create the pdf but is resulting in a very large file app 800000MB. Is there a better way pls? This is my code:

```
for i in range(0, noImages):
  image = Image.open(newimageList[i])



  if(i == 0):                       
    image.save(namePath, "PDF" ,quality=100, optimize=True, save_all=True)
  else:
    namePath2 = rootPDF+pdf_id+"temp.pdf"
    image.save(namePath2, "PDF" ,quality=100, optimize=True, save_all=True)

    pdfs = [namePath, namePath2]

    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for f in pdfs:
        merger.append(PdfFileReader(f), 'rb')
    with open(namePath, 'wb') as new_file:
        merger.write(new_file)
    os.remove(namePath2)
```

Comment: Are the images in grayscale or colour?

Comment: They are coloured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest is to convert the images to an intermediate multi-page TIFF file, and then convert that to pdf.

The software you need for that is `convert` from the [ImageMagick suite](https://imagemagick.org/) (an essential tool for everybody working with bitmap graphics) and `tiff2pdf` from [libtiff](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/).

First, convert all the JPEGS to an intermediate TIFF file.
This example presumes files named `page001.jpg`, `page002.jpg` et cetera. Adjust as needed:

```
convert -density 150 -units PixelsPerInch page*.jpg \
-adjoin intermediate.tiff
```

(You only need to specify the resolution with `density` if the files don't include resolution metadata.)

Then convert the intermediate to PDF using JPEG compression:

```
tiff2pdf -r 150 -j -o output.pdf intermediate.tiff
```

As an example, I used this technique to convert four scanned pages (JPEG format, sRGB color, 1216x1704 pixels) totalling 990098 bytes to a 651149 bytes PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [fpdf](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf)

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
# imagelist is the list with all image filenames
for image in imagelist:
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image(image,x,y,w,h)
pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
```

You can check out their [tutorial page](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/index.html) as well.